# How to send push notification from cloud function to devices (not to the users)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

It looks like FCM is the new way of sending messages to devices but I seem to fail to understand how to use this service for in-app service messages.

For instance: My server processes data in a cloud function triggered from a firestore database. When it completes, it should push a notification to all devices that new data has been computed.

I know I can do this with FCM but these messages are not designed for the user, they indicate that some background process should start its sync with the server, no user action is required or desired.

Is there currently no solution to such an approach? GCM has been deprecated and FCM seems to not allow me invoke a service to perform background operations when the app is not in foreground.

Did I outline a use-case currently not supported with google's technology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FCM supports two types of message:

- Notification messages, sometimes thought of as "display messages." These are handled by the FCM SDK automatically.
- Data messages, which are handled by the client app.

You want a data message, this is the format to use:

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "data":{
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "body" : "great match!",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages